# Update windows no internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-update

I have a couple servers i will be adding to our production environment however I would like to get the latest updates. Only problem is the Vlan they are configured on does not have internet.

I could switch to a Vlan that does have internet however I was wondering if anyone knows how I would go about getting the latest updates without an internet connection?

Comment: http://download.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: What about setting up a WSUS server that can reach the internet and these servers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used this in the past without issues [Wsus Offline Installer](http://download.wsusoffline.net/)